# How to turn one column of the matrix into all zeros?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix like this:
[image]

I search for mathmatical operation that would turn a given column (say $T_3$ or $T_4$) into all zeros not changing anything else about this matrix. How to do such thing in math?

Comment: In math, you could just say, "Let $A$ be the previous matrix, but with column 3 replaced by a zero vector." If that's not what you're looking for you'll have to be more precise by your "how to do such a thing".

Comment: Consider multiplying on the right by a square matrix of the appropriate size whose entries are the same as the identity except the given column is all $0$s. This is the elementary matrix corresponding to the column operation of multiplying a column by $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that in general for $A_{m\times n}B_{n\times n}=C_{m\times n}$ the i-th column of $C$ is the combination of the columns of $A$ with respect to the coefficient of the i-th column of $B$.

Then we can multiply by the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

to obtain a matrix with $T_4=0$ and similarly we can obtain a matrix with $T_3=0$.

Comment: Will it keep $T_2$
 values if they are not on the diagonal line?

Comment: @DuckQueen Yes of course, let try by direct check. Note that $A_{5x4}I_{4x4}=A_{5x4}$ and also recall that in general for $AB=C$ the i-th column of $C$ is the combination of the columns of $A$ with respect to the coefficient of the i-th column of $B$.

Comment: And how shell I do it when my matrix is not square (20 cols. 30 rows)?

Comment: @DuckQueen Also in the case of the OP it is not square, in general we have $A_{mxn}I_{nxn}=A_{mxn}$ for any $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much!)))